# Oracle SQL create view privileges

Tags: oracle, view, permissions

This is more of a theoritical question but I need help ASAP. Here it is:

> With the appropriate use of SQL queries, grant as system
>   administrators the required access privileges to a database user named
>   STD01, so he can create a view of a table named CUSTOMER, which
>   belongs to another database user STD00.

Can anyone help me with this?

I know that I have to grant him with the system privilege of CREATE (ANY) VIEW and also give him all the object privileges (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE) on the CUSTOMER table, but I have no idea how can I do that by using SQL...

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: Its a kind of a possible question for an exam I'm having tomorrow, can you help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To grant privilege to create a view:

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO STD01;
```

To grant the DML privileges:

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON STD00.CUSTOMER TO STD01;
```

But that's not all of the object privileges. If you did:

```
GRANT ALL ON STD00.CUSTOMER TO STD01;
```

you would also give other privileges such as `ALTER`, `INDEX`, `FLASHBACK`, etc.

Comment: If I grant him only the SELECT privilege, would it still work?

Comment: If you just `grant select` and `create view` then, yes, it will allow you to create a view on the `customer` table.

Comment: I've just tested this and worked fine, so thats why Im asking.
But I guess I'll better write the whole command tomorrow as you did above. You just never know with professors.. Thanks for the help!:)